datadog monitors - slack "info" notifications
I am experimenting with DataDog monitors. My goal is to send a notification to Slack channel whenever specific logs are seen.
Is it possible to set a "status" for alerts (info, error)? As I see in Slack, notifications always have a red sign near them that looks like an error.
It seems like the DataDog monitors are more for fail cases, rather than for simple notifications. Is there a way to achieve that with DataDog monitors, or with another way?
